# Apache mod_rewrite not work

Tags: apache, webserver

I am can enable mod_rewrite in Apache, in logs we can see error:

```
/Users/rustam/Documents/www/laravel/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

My virtual host in file in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/rustam/Documents/www/laravel/public/"
    ServerName laravel.loc
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory "/Users/rustam/Documents/www/laravel/public/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /Users/rustam/Documents/www/vhosts/logs/laravel_errors.log

</VirtualHost>
```

In config file `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` I am uncommented `module mod_rewrite`, and also set `AllowOverride` from `none` to `all` everywhere where I found it.

My `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

But still nothing is work, still error and 500 header, when I tried to change URL from `laravel.loc` to some route, like example `laravel.loc/telescope/`

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory.  Did you verify that the module exists?  As far as I know RewriteEngine should be in `httpd.conf`, not `.htaccess`

Comment: @Allan in `httpd.conf` param `LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so` is uncommented. But this only one param who has `rewrite` words in all file `httpd.conf`

Comment: I asked it the module *exists*, not if you uncommented it. Did you review [`mod_rewrite` at Apache.org](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)?

Comment: @Allan Sorry, but I don't understand. I checked mod_rewrite module at Apache.org but also don't understand what you mean. I don't know if module exists in my system, I'm was think it may attach to Apache, like all other modules.

Comment: The file, `mod-rewrite.so` must exist at the location specified. Also, `.htaccess` is a per directory config file. The RewriteEngine  needs to be in `httpd.conf.

Comment: @Allan I'm downloaded module and replaced specified location. Now it `LoadModule rewrite_module /etc/apache2/libs/mod_rewrite.so`. After that I'm restarted apache, but still the same error.